# Efficient rails deployment to a small EC2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, bundler, cpu

I've got a few rails apps running under different vhosts on a single small EC2 instance.  My automated deployment process for each involves running some rake tasks (migration, asset compilation, etc.), staging everything into a versioned directory and symlinking web root to it.  I'm serving the apps with Apache + Passenger.  Through this process (and the rebooting of passenger), I have ruby processes eating up 100% of CPU.  I understand why this is happening, but I need a way to throttle these processes down so that all of the other apps on the instance aren't as significantly impacted as they currently are.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've already come across this. But it's there to make EC2 deployment more convenient. https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber

There is also a Railscast on it at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2

Hopefully, these two resources will help you somewhere.